# Error creating a BLOB_STORAGE type external data source in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Here's the T-SQL I try to run:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE mySource WITH 
(TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://myContainer.blob.core.windows.net', CREDENTIAL = myCredential)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Msg 105057, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE statement failed because the value for the 'TYPE' option is invalid. Change the value for the 'TYPE' option and try again.
```

I've Googled for "Msg 105057" and I get nothing. My goal is to use the OPENROWSET function to bulk insert a JSON file from my Azure Storage account into my Azure Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 2):

It does support Blob Storage, but the TYPE needs to be 'HADOOP' and the location needs to use "wasbs" instead of "https":

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE mySource WITH 
(TYPE = HADOOP, LOCATION = 'wasbs://myContainer.blob.core.windows.net', CREDENTIAL = myCredential)
```

Comment: HADOOP != BLOB_STORAGE

Comment: While you'll get no argument from me, but this is what we do internally to create EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE against Blob Storage. We have dozens of these defined in our SQLDW and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Azure SQL Data Warehouse (aka Azure Synapse Analytics) does not support the BLOB_STORAGE type or the OPENROWSET function. This seems counter-intuitive, but it's not the 1st time Azure has disappointed me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver15

Note that 'Azure Synapse Analytics (SQL DW)' is not marked as 'Applies to" in these documents.